# Vertically center an image insider container element with just css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to vertically center some images inside their container `<li>` blocks using CSS but Im not sure how to go about it. I could resort to using javascript to calculate the height of the image and then do some math to center it vertically using margins but that seems clunky and stupid.

Is there any good CSS-based solution to accomplish vertical alignment without using fixed-margins (image height is variable)?

Images sticking to the top of their container li element:
[image: Images sticking to the top of their container li element]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using this css properties:

```
display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
```

Like this demo: [jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/P94YE/](http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/P94YE/)

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: I tried that but I think it only works when comparing divs that are on the same level not nested items like these.

Comment: Try to specify the line height to be the same as the height of the li.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using always..
            `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 0):

Fredy's answer is correct for modern browsers but doesn't work with IE pre 8.  Other techniques: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps! http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/center-div-with-dynamic-height/